# OpenAL doesn't work when using AVAudioRecorder and AVAudioPlayer

Tags: iphone, avaudioplayer, openal, avaudiorecorder

i have been troubled about audio problem for several days. i don't think OpenAL get along with AVAudio functions.

i have my own OpenAL class. ( wrapped the MyOpenAL class )
my app start to record using AVAudioRecorder. i stop recording. and then i clicked the "OpenAL Play"button that play any sound using OpenAL.
i can't hear it.
but i can hear my recording when i clicked the "AVAudioPlayer Play" button using AVAudioPlayer.

i tested oalTouch,avTouch,SpeakHear sample code.
they resulted same.
in oalTouch, when AVAudioPlayer stop, OpenAL stop playing simultaneously. this is why i think so.

Does OpenAL have the problem using AVAudio~ Functions together?

I was googling for a long time. but i couln't find out the solutions and the same problems issue.

thanks for reading mine.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using AVAudioRecorder (to record) and OpenAL (to playback) and they both go quite well. Just wanted to check if you use Play_And_Record as option when you initialize your AVAudioRecorder?

Comment: hi,
absolutely i do.


however, in the latest iOS version, i think it fix. 
now i tested oalTouch sample code.

in oalTouch Sample,
when i turn on music and i tapped the play button, i can listen to two source(water sound, orchestra sound ). 
and then when i turn off play button( not music button), two sound all stop in the older version. but in iOS 4.2 (my version) , it work right.